# Why my button's background is not changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't change my button's background.

HTML:

```
<div class="direct-link-box-container">
    <form class="direct-box-form">
    <input type="text" class="direct-link-box" placeholder="Paste your Torrent Link or Magnet">
    <input type="submit" class="get-button" value="Get">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
direct-link-box-container .get-button
    {
        background-color: #BDBDBD;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 1px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 50px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
    }
    .get-button-hover
    {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.get-button').hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('get-button-hover');
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass('get-button-hover');
         }
        );
    });
```

Comment: it does http://jsfiddle.net/pLqodmcm/1/

Comment: I know how to do it with css but can you please tell how to do it using Jquery?

Comment: @Pekka - it only (sort of) works because of a typo in the CSS - none of the styling in the first selector is applied though

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there **SHOULD'VE** been a leading `.` in your CSS snippet

```
.direct-link-box-container .get-button {
    background-color: #BDBDBD; 
    border: none; 
    border-radius: 1px; 
    height: 40px; 
    width: 50px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
} 
.direct-link-box-container .get-button-hover{
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ see specificity link below
    background-color: blue;
}
```

see CSS specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Is this how it is supposed to work?i added your css to it http://jsfiddle.net/pLqodmcm/2/

Comment: has a transition now, but I'm only guessing as Kshiti seems to have dropped off the face of the planet